# Is it safe to save requestToken and accessToken on user local device

Tags: android, security, oauth, oauth-2.0

Say, I am implementing an installed application (Desktop application and Android application), which is going to access Google services. I order to avoid user having to login multiple times, I decide to save its `requestToken` and `accessToken` to his local device.

As after I gone through several tutorial like http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/08/06/oauth-2-0-flow-android/, I find this is what most of the people is doing.

However, my concern is that, is it safe to do so? What if, a hacker obtained the saved `requestToken` and `accessToken` from user local device? Will security be compromised? Can the hacker pretend to be genuine user?

Note, as the application is going to be open source. Hence, anyone can have access to `clientID` and `clientSecret` for particular Google API.

Comment: So, does it solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have also used app token in my application. I have saved it to SharedPrefs with Private mode as:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                "app token", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

When you save a sharedPref with Private mode, it can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID). And whenever user logs out, clear all the sharedPrefs, so that, there will not be any copy of your app token saved in local storage of the device. This should be safe to use, and security will be ensured.

**Update:**
App token should not be stored in SharedPreference since if the device is rooted, the sharedPrefs file can be exposed. [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) can be used to store token but again it can also be exposed if device is rooted. Best way is to encrypt a token with a strong encryption algo and then save it into AccountManager. The key used for encryption should be unique with every user and device combination so that even if key is compromised, hacker would be able to retrieve only data for that specific user and not all.

Comment: OK. How about desktop application? It don't have such "MODE_PRIVATE" facility. I just want to ensure hacker is unable to do any nasty thing using requestToken and accessToken :) If I am sure about that, I can save it in desktop application's config file too. Currently, I am not sure about it.

Comment: And I believe if the device is being root, the hacker still have way to retrieve out the information from your SharedPrefs?

Comment: When mobile is rooted, the user will have all the rights to access all the info from your device. If you are concerned about this issue then you can use Encryption techniques to ensure the security of the app token. After encrypting, you save the file to sharedPrefs, it will good solution then. For more android app security related info you can see following: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022596.do

Comment: For desktop app also, the encryption technique can be a good solution.